# как посчитать сумму всех звезд (отзывов) в коллекции?laravel

Tags: laravel

```
//все отзывы
$reviews = Review::where('user_id', 15)->get();
//количество отзывов
$numberReviews = $reviews->count();
```

у отзыва есть поле rating там число
как посчитать грамотно сумму всех звезд ?
в цикле или какая то функция в laravel есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом коллекции [sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum)

В вашем случае:

```php
$reviews->sum('rating');
```